# I want to put the output value in a column of Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, replace

As you can see what I am trying here is to remove M and then multiply the number with 1024 and in else part I am removing K. when the whole code will executed I want to put the values in a column but how?

```
for col in play_store_data['Size']:
  if type(col) != float:
    if 'M' in col:
      col = col[:-1]
      col = float(col)*1024
    else:
      col = col[:-1]
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1vPsxR_-ucr831ASXDwhwCXg1HT07AnZH

here you can find the data that You need.

Comment: Please share dataset with expected output

Comment: Answer it plzz ASAP

Comment: Your sample data should be included __in__ your question. And _if_ you're going to link to an external document it should be shared publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your dataset looks like this:

```
playstore_data = pd.DataFrame({"Size":["1234M","4567K",np.nan,"7657M"]})
print(playstore_data)

        Size
    0  1234M
    1  4567K
    2    NaN
    3  7657M
```

Then use `series.apply()`:

```
playstore_data.Size[~playstore_data.Size.isna()] = playstore_data.Size[~playstore_data.Size.isna()].apply(lambda x: float(x[:-1])*1024 if "M" in x else float(x[:-1]))

print(playstore_data)

              Size
    0  1.26362e+06
    1         4567
    2          NaN
    3  7.84077e+06
```

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable                                                                             I am having this error

Comment: Means your dataset has NaN values too. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you brother, I found my result. Allah Bless you:)